# Shiny Datatables - focus after page load

Tags: r, datatable, shiny, dt

So I'm trying to make it so that a datatable in my shiny app scrolls to the top and focuses on an element after someone clicks on the next page. The following code is working, but the problem is that the focus works whenever its drawn (because of drawCallBack)

```
options=list(pageLength=50, drawCallBack = DT::JS(
      'function (paginateScroll) {
        $("html, body").animate({
          scrollTop: 0
        }, 300);
        $("th:first-child").focus();
        $(".paginate_button").bind("click", paginateScroll);
      }'
    ))
```

I know there's an event called page (https://datatables.net/reference/event/page) which should work, but I can't seem to get the code right. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: I'm using the development version of DT, and trying his examples like callback = JS('table.page("next").draw(false);') just makes my table not show up

Comment: Unless I am misunderstanding something, the JS code you gave doesn't do anything. In `callback` the event `table.on("page.dt", function() ....` should happen only when the page is changed like you want so maybe that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't quite understand what your goal is, but I see that you want to run JS only when the page is changed, rather than when it is drawn. Here is some JS that only runs when the page is changed. Hope this helps:

```
library(shiny) 
library(DT)

shinyApp( 
  ui = fluidPage(
    mainPanel(DT::dataTableOutput("test")
    )
  ), 
  server = function(input, output,session) {     
    output$test <- DT::renderDataTable({
      mtcars

    },
    callback=DT::JS(
      'table.on("page.dt",function() {
        alert("Page has changed");
      })
      '
    )
    )
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked. I think I was putting the callback code into options and maybe that's why it wasn't working? Actually I might have also been confused between drawCallback which is a datatable function and callback itself